Generalized Logarithmic Integrals
$$\int_{-1}^1 \ln^m(1-x)\ln^n(1+x)\,dx\tag1$$
$$\int_{0}^1 \ln^m(1-x)\ln^n(1+x)\,dx\tag2$$
I have been trying to generalize these two integrals from quite some time and I am unable to figure out means to do so.
Not so sure, but here is one way I could think of regarding $(1)$,
$$\int_{-1}^1\ln^n(1+t)\ln^m(1-t)\,dt=\lim_{(a,b)\to(0,0)}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial a^n}\left(\frac{\partial^m}{\partial b^m}\left(2^{a+b-1}\beta(a,b)\right)\right)$$
Here I face one small problem, conversion from $(1)\to(2)$, requires $m=n$ but what about $m\ne n$?
